# gcc linking library with -l and -L

Tags: c, gcc, network-programming

I'm having compiling error when trying to link a library. Here's the error along with my compilation commands

```
gcc snw-server.c -Wall -g  -L\ -lpacketErrorSend -o snw-server
/tmp/cc7dekxv.o: In function `main':
/home/mike/CSCI446/project3/snw-server.c:113: undefined reference to `packetErrorSend'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:5: recipe for target 'file' failed
make: *** [file] Error 1
```

I was slightly confused initially about the -L command. The library file lives in the current directory where all the other files are located. Here's what files are in my directory.

```
libpacketErrorSend.a  Makefile  packetErrorSend.h  snw-client.c  snw-server.c
```

and here's what my Makefile looks like

```
 file: snw-server.c snw-client.c
         gcc snw-server.c -Wall -g  -L\ -lpacketErrorSend -o snw-server
         gcc snw-client.c -Wall -g  -L\ -lpacketErrorSend -o snw-client 


  clean:
         rm -f snw-server snw-client
```

I made sure I included packetErrorSend.h in the .c files. I'm not sure I linked the library properly.

The packetErrorSend function is built by our instructor to use the same arguments as send(2) (networking), but it loses packets. It works using send, but doesn't compile when trying to link the library and changing the function to packetErrorSend.

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: `-L\ -lpacketErrorSend` ??? => `-L . -lpacketErrorSend`

Comment: The current directory is not signified by "\" it is "."

Answer (score 3):

The `\` character exscapes the following space causing it to not be treated as an option separator by the shell.  So `-L\ -lpacketErrorSend` ends up as a single argument, telling the linker to look in "`-lpacketErrorSend`" for library files.  Since that directory doesn't exist, it effectively does nothing.  Then, since you have no `-l` options, no libraries are linked.

What you probably want is

```
gcc snw-server.c -Wall -g  -L. -lpacketErrorSend -o snw-server
```

Using `.` tells the linker to look in `.` -- the current directory.